# Symfony route being lost when importing multiple yaml files

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I am [setting up an admin](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/getting_started.html#step-1-define-sonataadminbundle-routes) for two entities in my system ("Link" and "Contact"), however I have a problem when I import a second `admin.yml` file. This is my working `config.yml`:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: @AyrshireMinisContactBundle/Resources/config/admin.yml }
```

However, when I add this line just below I lose all the routing attached to the `AyrshireMinisContactBundle` and get a myriad of errors thrown at me (essentially saying that the rout for the Contact bundle cannot be found):

```
- { resource: @AyrshireMinisCommonBundle/Resources/config/admin.yml }
```

How can I configure my `config.yml` to allow for both admin files to be pulled in for these entities?

The error:

> CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Runtime: "An exception
>   has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to
>   generate a URL for the named route
>   "admin_ayrshireminis_contact_contact_create" as such route does not
>   exist.") in "SonataAdminBundle:Block:block_admin_list.html.twig" at
>   line 39."

Comment: Any particular reason for using the config.yml to import routes instead of routing.yml?

Comment: @PedroMM I am following this tutorial (http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/getting_started.html#importing-it-in-the-main-config-yml) For some reason Sonata suggests loading it in `config.yml`. The `admin.yml` file doesn't _only_ hold routing, there are other config settings in there too. Any idea why I lose the routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that this was caused by not having a correctly named service in `admin.yml` for both bundles.

When I was getting the error I had `sonata.admin.post` set for both "Contact" and "Link" entities, but after renaming them as follows my second entry under `imports` worked a treat.

Contact admin.yml:

```
services:
    sonata.contact.admin.post: # <-- line changed
        class: AyrshireMinis\ContactBundle\Admin\ContactAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Leads", label: "Contacts" }
        arguments:
            - ~
            - AyrshireMinis\ContactBundle\Entity\Contact
            - ~
        calls:
            - [ setTranslationDomain, [AyrshireMinisContactBundle]]
```

Link admin.yml:

```
services:
    sonata.link.admin.post: # <-- line changed
        class: AyrshireMinis\CommonBundle\Admin\LinkAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Links", label: "Links" }
        arguments:
            - ~
            - AyrshireMinis\CommonBundle\Entity\Link
            - ~
        calls:
            - [ setTranslationDomain, [AyrshireMinisCommonBundle]]
```

HTH someone in future. [Further reading](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-0/doc/reference/architecture.html).